# Typo3 10.4 TCA Slug

Tags: typo3, slug

I created my extension with this TCA Slug configuration (equal to UID) :
In backend , when i create a new object, the field slug is not correctly populated.
I solved this problem by a Hook ($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass'])  :

QUESTION : Is there a method to populate the field slug correctly only in TCA?

Thank you in advance for your kind reply.

```
    'slug' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'slug',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'slug',
            'size' => 255,
            'generatorOptions' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'uid',
                ],
                'fieldSeparator' => '/',
            ],
            'fallbackCharacter' => '-',
            'eval'              => 'uniqueInSite',
            'default'           => '',
        ],
    ],
```